# Force Wcf Client Proxy to NOT cache connections

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, proxy

I've a client-server application that communicate via Wcf. the client code uses the auto-generated Wcf client proxy.

Because my Wcf Service is behind a load balancer, each call to the service must create a new connection, otherwise my load-balancer would not be able to... well, balance the load.

Testing the following sample code:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client svc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
result = svc.GetData(111);

svc = new Service1Client();
result = svc.GetData(222);
```

I noticed both instances used the same connection.
I tried adding

```
ClientBase<ConsoleApplication4.ServiceReference1.IService1>.CacheSetting = CacheSetting.AlwaysOff;
```

But still got the same result.
What am I missing? how can I force Wcf so that every new instance of the proxy, a new connection would be created?

Comment: Are you sure it's a caching issue and not an issue with the InstanceContextMode?  The default is PerSession.

Comment: @Tim - InstanceContextMode determins when should the server create a new instance of the service and when to reuse it.
What I'm asking is how to force the *client* create a new connection